# Using edit menu commands from menu bar app

Tags: cocoa

I have an app which is run from the menu bar only (LSUIElement is set in the info.plist) which means there is no main menu except the menu I attached to the status item. The problem is I would like to enable some edit commands when using an NSTextView (like command-c to copy) but all command keys seem to be disabled since the app is technically not active (I get beeps when trying any key combinations).

Is there anyway to add a standard edit menu somewhere and enable command keys that would redirect to it? I'm thinking there could be a hack to make the app temporarily active or something but I can't figure anything out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not disabled. They're *gone*, because you deleted them.

You need to put back your Main Menu.

If you use version control, you may be able to resurrect it from the past using that. If not, you'll have to create a new project, copy anything custom from your Main Menu nib (if you even still have one) into that one, and move that nib into your actual project to be your new Main Menu nib.

The Edit menu commands, window-related commands (e.g., Close), and numerous other commands all live in the Main Menu. If you delete the Main Menu, you don't have those features anymore.

Your Main Menu isn't visible in a UI element app, but that's not a reason to delete it—it's a reason to keep it, even though your app won't have the menu bar, because not being visible means that it won't peek out from behind the curtain but will remain there keeping the magic of your keyboard shortcuts working.

Comment: You're right, UI agents can have a hidden main menu. Actually the problem wasn't that it was deleted in the NIB but all actions in the edit menu got deleted in InterfaceBuilder when I copied/pasted the menu around before. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Today I was able to fix this issue by creating a new project and just copying and pasting the menu into my xib. Didn't need to copy anything from my existing xib and so on.